# Simulate input in UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

Is it possible to simulate keyboard and mouse input programattically in UWP applications?

If it is - how?

I've found solutions for Windows Forms only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the classes in the Windows.UI.Input.Preview.Injection namespace for this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Comment: Just what i need. Thank you.

Comment: How do you simulate scrolling?

Comment: Take a look at https://blog.mzikmund.com/2018/01/injecting-input-in-uwp-apps/ and the related sample code on github for an example of injecting keyboard and mouse input.  https://github.com/MartinZikmund/blog-2018/tree/master/InjectedMouse

Comment: The answer mentioned is only applicable for Windows 10 build 16299 or above. 
How does one achieve the same thing in an earlier version?